# Мотоцикла и учреждения

Tags: род, старая-грамматика

В *"Поднятой целине" мотоцикла* и *учреждения* женского рода. Что это: местный говор или норма того времени?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня есть *"Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в русский язык"* (Изд-во Левенсона, 1912). Так вот в нём **мотоцикл** мужского рода.
Что касается *учреждения*, то вот цитата из Ломоносова, где это слово используется как синоним организации (в Нацкорпусе целый ряд примеров из XVIII-XIX веков):

> Благодарность их несумнительна и тем
> вяще возрастет, чем чувствительнее окажется возрастающая польза,
> каковую обещает сие прехвальное учреждение. *[М. В. Ломоносов. Слово благодарственное Ея Императорскому Величеству на освящение Академии Художеств, именем ея говоренное (1764)]*

Из этого, я думаю, вполне можно сделать вывод, что Шолохов изображал либо говор, либо просторечие. Тем более что в его книгах это встречается повсеместно.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Видимо, так и есть.

Comment: @Nektoid *...каковую обещает **сие** прехвальное учреждение.* Я считаю, что Ваш ломоносовский  пример *никак* не доказывает, что слово "учреждения" когда-то использовалось в женском роде. *Сие* — это и есть местоимение среднего рода. В словаре: СЕЙ, сего, сему, сим, о сём; м.; СИЯ, сей, сию и (нар.-разг.) сю, сею, о сей; ж.; **СИЕ**, сего, сему, сим, о сём; **ср.** (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова разумеется, у Ломоносова *учреждение* в среднем роде. Я написал: *Что касается (чего?) учреждения*.